# Suggested way to initialize a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Is there a suggested way on how to initialize a struct in C? For example:

```
Book romeo = {"Romeo & Juliet", "Shakespeare", 1600};
```

```
Book inferno;
inferno.title = "Divine Comedy";
inferno.author = "Dante";
inferno.year = 1400;
```

Is one way preferred over the other one? I would think for readability the second one is easier, but if there are a ton of fields it might become unwieldy. Additionally, is there any way to specify the variable name in the first method, something like:

```
Book romeo = {title="...", author="...", year="...");
```

Comment: I guess the better way depends on availability of information, if the information is known & it does not changes during the course of running of program the first method is good second method is used in case of update of members during the course of program

Comment: C defines the first as _initialization_, the 2nd as _assignment_.

Comment: cannot 'assign' strings via a `=` rather need to use a function similar to: `Book inferno;
strcpy( inferno.title, Divine Comedy" );
strcpy( inferno.author, "Dante" );
inferno.year = 1400;   However, if the fields `title` and `author` are pointers rather than arrays, then `=` will result in a pointer to the location in read-only memory where the actual string is located

Comment: What is the definition of `Book`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is one way preferred over the other one?

Note: C defines the first as *initialization*, the 2nd as *assignment*.

Yes, global object can be initialized, but not assigned with global code.

```
// Possible
Book romeo = {"Romeo & Juliet", "Shakespeare", 1600};

Book inferno;

// Not possible outside a function.
inferno.title = "Divine Comedy";
inferno.author = "Dante";
inferno.year = 1400;
```

> is there any way to specify the variable name in the first method

Since C99, members can be specified in any order, complete or not.

```
Book romeo = {. title = "Romeo & Juliet", .author = "Shakespeare", .year = 1600};
Book romeo = {.year = 1600, . title = "Romeo & Juliet", .author = "Shakespeare" };
Book romeo = {. title = "Romeo & Juliet", .author = "Shakespeare" };  // .year takes on value 0
```

Comment: thanks, why can't global objects be assigned with global code?

Comment: @carl.hiass All code must exist local within a function.  There is no "global code".

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally, is there any way to specify the variable name in the
> first method, something like:

hope below code helps

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Book {
    char *title;
    unsigned int year;
} Book;

int main() 
{
    Book B1 = { .year = 1999};
    Book B2 = {.title= "Jason Bourne",  .year = 1999};
    printf("B1.year = %d\n", B1.year);
    printf("B2.title = %s B2.year = %d\n", B2.title, B2.year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @sras -- thanks, why do you do `typedef struct Book {...} Book` instead of `typedef struct {...} Book` ? Is that more helpful to the compiler or what does the additional `Book` do?

Comment: I don't see any special advantage to compiler both versions work perfectly, but may be its easier to read in the first line itself  in case the structure is too big.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way but not exactly as you said.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct { int k; int l; int a[2]; } T;
typedef struct { int i;  T t; } S;
T x = {.l = 43, .k = 42, .a[1] = 19, .a[0] = 18 }; // x initialized to {42, 43, {18, 19} }
int main(void)
{
    S l = { 1,          // initializes l.i to 1
           .t = x,      // initializes l.t to {42, 43, {18, 19} }
           .t.l = 41,   // changes l.t to {42, 41, {18, 19} }
           .t.a[1] = 17 // changes l.t to {42, 41, {18, 17} }
          };
    printf("l.t.k is %d\n", l.t.k); // .t = x sets l.t.k to 42 explicitly
                                // .t.l = 41 would zero out l.t.k implicitly
}
```

Moreover, you should visit [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization.) once
and please check [here](http://en.cppreference.com)  before you ask a question.